# Eclipse maximum xml file size

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm making and android app, which needs 2 big arrays. Each one has a separate xml file. One is 2,5 MB and another one is almost 10 MB. Now, whenever I try to save workspace, the process of Building Workspace gets stuck at 46%. I changed my eclipse.ini file to

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

and it still gets stuck. What should I do?

Comment: Don't edit it in Eclipse, and turn off validation for those files. You could try temporarily removing them manually and restoring them.